# barba.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

js

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined**

### this is the code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var pagetrans = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
        start: function() {
            Promise.all([this.newContainerLoading, this.left()]).then(this.right.bind(this));
        },
        left: function() {
            var transon = $(".transition").animate({left: '0px'});
            return $(this.oldContainer).transon.Promise();
        },
        right: function(el) {
            var _this = this;
            var el = $(this.newContainer);
            $(this.oldContainer).hide();
            el.css({
                visibility : 'visible',
                opacity : 0
            });
            var transoff = $(".transition").animate({left: '100%'});
            el.transoff, 400, function() {
                _this.done();
            };
        }
    });
    Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {
        return pagetrans;
    };
    Barba.Pjax.start();
});
```

the transition not working fine
just start slide left and doesn't back right

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check if it works, but I think `promise()` is the correct name, not `Promise()`.

```
return $(this.oldContainer).transon.promise();
```